# X axis is not displayed in cartesian charts ExtJS 6.5.3 after upgrade from ExtJS 5 to 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic, extjs6.5

I have tab panel with items cartesian chart. on loading page only y-axis is getting displayed n the page. 
Same code works fine in sencha fiddle but not in my application. please let me know if anybody knows this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for above issue, I have added position:absolute to the chart panel divs and issue got resolved.